# Error in uploading and saving CSV file in streamlit

Tags: python, csv, streamlit

This is the code that I've written for csv file upload

```
import os
def save_uploadedfile(uploadedfile):
     with open(uploadedfile.name,"wb") as f:
         f.write(uploadedfile.getbuffer())

     return st.success("Saved File".format(uploadedfile.name))
```

```
import streamlit as st
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Add dataset (csv) ",type=['csv'])
if uploaded_file is not None:
    file_details = {"FileName":uploaded_file.name,"FileType":uploaded_file.type}
    st.write(file_details)
    save_uploadedfile(uploaded_file)
```

For some reason the csv file isn't the same after it's uploaded.
The original file is in this format

```
S.no,Course Name,Course Duration,Category,Description,id,Course ID
1,...
2,...
3,...
```

whereas the uploaded file looks like this

```
,S.no,Course Name,Course Duration,Category,Description,id,Course ID
0,1,other data
1,2,...
2,3,..
```

Why is the extra column being added in the beginning ?

The case was the same when I tried to add the csv file to a dataframe and then converted it to csv.

Comment: What is `st` library?

Comment: @OlaGalal streamlit , sorry I forgot to add that line. ```import streamlit as st```

Comment: That column is called **index** it is included by default to show the index of every row. I hope  this answered your question.

Comment: My question is, what is it that you want to do? Your main objective is not clear.

Comment: @JamiuShaibu I want to use the csv to perform some nlp related operations. But the query is now solved , I just added some lines of code to delete the first column.